# How to make a slider that dynamically creates and destroys 2d game objects in a circle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I created an editor tool that creates game objects in a circle, equally apart from each other (code below). It has a create button, so parameters are adjusted before the create is smashed. I would like to see changes made dynamically in the scene view rather. How can I adjust the following parameters with a slider rather:

1. Create or destroy game objects using an object count slider, whiles adjusting to keep the objects the same angle apart
2. dynamically adjust the game objects by changing a radius slider
3. rotate all objects on the circle (like spinning a wheel) using an angle slider

**CircleSpawn**

```
public class CircleSpawn : MonoBehaviour {
    public float radius;
    public int numOfItems;
    public GameObject clonedObject;
    public List<GameObject> spawnedObjects;
}
```

**CircleSpawnEditor**

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(CircleSpawn))]
public class CircleSpawnEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        var tar = (CircleSpawn)target;

        //set its values
        tar.radius = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Radius:", tar.radius);
        tar.numOfItems = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of Items:", tar.numOfItems);
        tar.clonedObject = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(tar.clonedObject,
                   typeof(GameObject), true);

        //Inspector button for creating the objects in the Editor
        if (GUILayout.Button("Create"))
        {
            //clean up old objects
            if (tar.spawnedObjects != null)
            {
                foreach (var ob in tar.spawnedObjects)
                {
                    DestroyImmediate(ob);
                }
            }
            tar.spawnedObjects = new List<GameObject>();

            float angleBetween = 360.0f / tar.numOfItems;
            float angle = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= tar.numOfItems; i++)
            {
                //for each object, find a rotation and position
                var rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
                var localPos = rot * Vector3.right * tar.radius;
                tar.spawnedObjects.Add(Instantiate(tar.clonedObject,
                tar.transform.position + localPos, rot));
                angle += angleBetween;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Create or destroy game objects using an object count slider, whiles adjusting to keep the objects the same angle apart

Use an [`IntSlider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.IntSlider.html) for `numOfItems` and *re-create* the objects when:

```c#
numOfItems != spawnedObjects.Count
```

> Dynamically adjust the game objects by changing a radius slider

Use a [`Slider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Slider.html) for `radius`, and when it changes, iterate over `spawnedObjects` and move them by:

```c#
pos = rot * Vector3.right * tar.radius
```

> Rotate all objects on the circle (like spinning a wheel) using an angle slider

Use a [`Slider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Slider.html) for `spin`, and when it changes, iterate over `spawnedObjects` and rotate them by:

```c#
rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, tar.spin + angle)
```

---

> CircleSpawn:

```c#
public class CircleSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float radius, radiusLast, spin, spinLast;
    public int numOfItems;
    public GameObject clonedObject;
    public List<GameObject> spawnedObjects;
}
```

> CircleSpawnEditor:

```c#
[CustomEditor(typeof(CircleSpawn))]
public class CircleSpawnEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
    {
        var tar = (CircleSpawn)target;    
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Radius"); // Set as required
        tar.radius = EditorGUILayout.Slider(tar.radius, 0f, 100f);          
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Angle"); // Set as required
        tar.spin = EditorGUILayout.Slider(tar.spin, 0f, 360f);              
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Number of Items"); // Set as required
        tar.numOfItems = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider(tar.numOfItems, 0, 36);  
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Object");
        tar.clonedObject = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(tar.clonedObject, 
        typeof(GameObject), true);

        float angle, angleBetween = 360.0f / tar.numOfItems;

        if (tar.spawnedObjects == null)
            tar.spawnedObjects = new List<GameObject>();

        // Solution #1    
        if (tar.spawnedObjects.Count != tar.numOfItems)
        {
            foreach (var ob in tar.spawnedObjects)
                DestroyImmediate(ob);

            tar.spawnedObjects.Clear();
            angle = 0f;

            for (int i = 0; i < tar.numOfItems; i++)
            {
                var rot = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, tar.spin + angle);
                var localPos = rot * Vector3.right * tar.radius;    
                tar.spawnedObjects.Add(Instantiate(tar.clonedObject,
                tar.transform.position + localPos, rot));
                angle += angleBetween;
            }
        }

        // Solutions #2 & 3    
        if (!Mathf.Approximately(tar.spin, tar.spinLast) ||
            !Mathf.Approximately(tar.radius, tar.radiusLast))
        {
            tar.spinLast = tar.spin;
            tar.radiusLast = tar.radius;    
            angle = 0f;

            for (int i = 0; i < tar.numOfItems; i++)
            {
                var rot = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, tar.spin + angle);
                var localPos = rot * Vector3.right * tar.radius;    
                tar.spawnedObjects[i].transform.position = 
                tar.transform.position + localPos;
                tar.spawnedObjects[i].transform.rotation = rot;
                angle += angleBetween;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lece would really appreciate if you could look at this related question I asked. Any help will really go a long way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469571/how-to-update-one-bezier-curve-as-another-is-moved-using-a-custom-editor

Comment: @Lece Still trying to get it done. I just put up a bounty for the question.

Comment: Hi @Bane. Sorry, I've been away and hadn't looked. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are few problems in your code:

**1**.Notice how there is one extra prefab created. Basically the number of items created is `numOfItems + 1` instead of the value of `numOfItems`.

That's because of this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= tar.numOfItems; i++)
```

That should be `i < tar.numOfItems` not `i <= tar.numOfItems;.`

**2**.You are not clearing the List. After destroying the items, clear the list too with `tar.Clear();`. If you don't do this, you will have list with null items that will keep growing.

---

To accomplish what's in your question, you will need a way to detect when the radius and `numOfItems` value changes. You need something similar to the `Update` function. There is none if you derive your script from `Editor` instead of `MonoBehaviour`.

To get something similar to the `Update` function event while deriving your script from `Editor`, subscribe to the `EditorApplication.update` event in the `OnEnable` function and unsubscribe from it in the `OnDisable` function. This should handle your *#1* and *#2* questions

To rotate all of them at the-same time, use the [`transform.RotateAround`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) function. This should handle your *#3* question.

I spent time yesterday to see how easy this is and following everything I mentioned above, below is what I came up with:

---

[image]

Below is the code. It can be improved. Most things are repeatable so I tried as much to put them in a function and used `enum` to determine which things to execute depending on the slider. Things shortened the code almost twice the original size. You don't have to use this code directly but you can use it to learn what I did and make yours if you prefer:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(CircleSpawn))]
public class CircleSpawnEditor : Editor
{
    private CircleSpawn targetObj;
    private static float previousRadius;
    private static int previousNumOfItems;
    private static float previousAngleIncrement;

    private static float angleIncrement = 0;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        var tar = (CircleSpawn)target;
        targetObj = tar;

        makeSlider("Radius", tar.radius, 0f, 10, 24, UpdateType.RADIUS);

        makeSlider("Number of Items", tar.numOfItems, 0f, 100, 24, UpdateType.RESPAWN);

        makeSlider("Angle", angleIncrement, 0f, 360, 24, UpdateType.ANGLE);

        //set its values
        tar.radius = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Radius:", tar.radius);
        tar.numOfItems = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Number of Items:", tar.numOfItems);
        angleIncrement = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Angle:", angleIncrement);

        tar.clonedObject = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(tar.clonedObject,
                   typeof(GameObject), true);

        //Inspector button for creating the objects in the Editor
        if (GUILayout.Button("Create"))
        {
            RespawnNumOfItems();
        }
    }

    void makeSlider(string label, float value, float min, float max, int space, UpdateType updateType)
    {
        GUILayout.Space(2);
        GUILayout.Label(label);
        if (updateType == UpdateType.RADIUS)
            targetObj.radius = GUILayout.HorizontalSlider(targetObj.radius, min, max);
        if (updateType == UpdateType.RESPAWN)
            targetObj.numOfItems = (int)GUILayout.HorizontalSlider(targetObj.numOfItems, min, max);
        if (updateType == UpdateType.ANGLE)
            angleIncrement = GUILayout.HorizontalSlider(angleIncrement, min, max);

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        var defaultAlignment3 = GUI.skin.label.alignment;
        GUILayout.Label(min.ToString());
        GUI.skin.label.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperRight;
        GUILayout.Label(max.ToString());
        GUI.skin.label.alignment = defaultAlignment3;
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Space(space);
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        EditorApplication.update += Update;
    }
    void OnDisable()
    {
        EditorApplication.update -= Update;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (targetObj != null)
        {
            float clampedNewRadius = Mathf.Clamp(targetObj.radius, 0f, float.MaxValue);

            //Check if Radius changed
            if (RadiusChanged())
            {
                //Debug.Log("Radius Changed: " + targetObj.radius);
                previousRadius = clampedNewRadius;
                targetObj.radius = clampedNewRadius;
                UpdateRadius();
            }


            int clampedNewNumOfItems = Mathf.Clamp(targetObj.numOfItems, 0, int.MaxValue);

            //Check if NumOfItems changed
            if (NumOfItemsChanged())
            {
                //Debug.Log("NumOfItems Changed: " + previousNumOfItems);
                previousNumOfItems = clampedNewNumOfItems;
                targetObj.numOfItems = clampedNewNumOfItems;
                RespawnNumOfItems();
            }

            float clampedAngle = Mathf.Clamp(angleIncrement, 0, int.MaxValue);

            //Check if Angle changed
            if (AngleChanged())
            {
                //Debug.Log("Angle Changed: " + previousAngleIncrement);
                UpdateAngle();
                previousAngleIncrement = clampedAngle;
                angleIncrement = clampedAngle;
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateAngle()
    {
        UpdateTransform(UpdateType.ANGLE);
    }

    private void RespawnNumOfItems()
    {
        if (targetObj.spawnedObjects == null)
            targetObj.spawnedObjects = new List<GameObject>();

        //clean up old objects
        if (targetObj.spawnedObjects != null)
        {
            // Debug.LogWarning("Destroyed");
            foreach (var ob in targetObj.spawnedObjects)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(ob);
            }
        }

        //Clear list
        targetObj.spawnedObjects.Clear();
        //Debug.LogWarning("Cleared List");

        UpdateTransform(UpdateType.RESPAWN);
    }

    private void UpdateRadius()
    {
        UpdateTransform(UpdateType.RADIUS);
    }

    void UpdateTransform(UpdateType updateType)
    {
        float angleBetween = 360.0f / targetObj.numOfItems;
        float angle = 0;

        if (targetObj != null)

            for (int i = 0; i < targetObj.numOfItems; i++)
            {
                //For each object, find a rotation and position
                var rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
                var localPos = rot * Vector3.right * targetObj.radius;

                //Debug.LogWarning("Updated");

                if (updateType == UpdateType.RADIUS)
                {
                    //Make sure that loop is within range
                    if (targetObj.spawnedObjects != null && i < targetObj.spawnedObjects.Count)
                    {
                        GameObject obj = targetObj.spawnedObjects[i];
                        if (obj != null)
                        {
                            Transform trans = obj.transform;
                            trans.position = targetObj.transform.position + localPos;
                            trans.rotation = rot;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (updateType == UpdateType.RESPAWN)
                {
                    if (targetObj.clonedObject != null)
                    {
                        GameObject objToAdd = Instantiate(targetObj.clonedObject, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
                        objToAdd.transform.position = targetObj.transform.position + localPos;
                        objToAdd.transform.rotation = rot;
                        targetObj.spawnedObjects.Add(objToAdd);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Debug.LogError("Please assign the clonedObject prefab in the Scene");
                    }
                }
                else if (updateType == UpdateType.ANGLE)
                {
                    //Make sure that loop is within range
                    if (targetObj.spawnedObjects != null && i < targetObj.spawnedObjects.Count)
                    {
                        GameObject obj = targetObj.spawnedObjects[i];
                        if (obj != null)
                        {
                            Transform trans = obj.transform;
                            Vector3 tagetPoint = targetObj.transform.position;
                            //Decide if we should rotate left or rigt
                            if (previousAngleIncrement > angleIncrement)
                                trans.RotateAround(tagetPoint, Vector3.forward, angleIncrement);
                            else
                                trans.RotateAround(tagetPoint, -Vector3.forward, angleIncrement);
                        }

                    }
                }
                if (updateType != UpdateType.ANGLE)
                    angle += angleBetween;
            }

        //Uncomment to test auto angle rotation over frame
        //testAngle();
    }

    void testAngle()
    {
        float speed = 0.005f;
        angleIncrement = (float)EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup * speed;
    }

    private bool RadiusChanged()
    {
        bool changed = !Mathf.Approximately(targetObj.radius, previousRadius)
            && !(targetObj.radius < 0);
        return changed;
    }

    private bool NumOfItemsChanged()
    {
        bool changed = (targetObj.numOfItems != previousNumOfItems)
            && !(targetObj.numOfItems < 0);
        return changed;
    }


    private bool AngleChanged()
    {
        bool changed = !Mathf.Approximately(angleIncrement, previousAngleIncrement)
           && !(angleIncrement < 0);
        return changed;
    }

    public enum UpdateType
    {
        RADIUS, RESPAWN, ANGLE
    }
}
```