# How to update one Bezier curve as another is moved using a custom editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating Bézier curves using the code below which I got from  [here](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/). I have also made a `BezierPair` game object which has two Bézier curves as child objects.

From the respective images below and BezierPair, where `points[0]`...`points[3]` is represented as `P0`...`P3`:

1. I want `P0` of each Bézier curve always remain the same when one is moved. In other words I want them to move together always, with the option of turning this movement off.

[image]

2. Say `P1` of both curves are apart. How can I make `P1` of each curve move in the same direction covering the same distance?

[image]

3. Say `P2` of both curves are apart. How can I make `P2` of one curve mirror `P2` of another curve along a line joining  `P0` and `P3`? Note that the mirror line would be taken from the curve 1 in the example below because `curve1`'s `P2` is moved. If `curve2`'s `P2` is moved, then the mirror line will be taken from `curve2`'s `P0P3`.

[image]

I don’t want to do this at run time. So a custom editor has to be used. 
I tried solving 1. in the code below but the position for the second curve wouldn’t update without my selecting BezierPair in the hierarchy window

Bezier:

```
public static class Bezier {

public static Vector3 GetPoint (Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2,   Vector3 p3, float t) {
t = Mathf.Clamp01(t);
float oneMinusT = 1f - t;
return
    oneMinusT * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * p0 +
    3f * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * t * p1 +
    3f * oneMinusT * t * t * p2 +
    t * t * t * p3;
}

public static Vector3 GetFirstDerivative (Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3, float t) {
t = Mathf.Clamp01(t);
float oneMinusT = 1f - t;
return
    3f * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * (p1 - p0) +
    6f * oneMinusT * t * (p2 - p1) +
    3f * t * t * (p3 - p2);
}
}
```

BezierCurve:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class BezierCurve : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector3[] points;
LineRenderer lr;
public int numPoints = 49;
bool controlPointsChanged = false;

bool isMoving = false;

public void Reset () {
points = new Vector3[] {
    new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f),
    new Vector3(2f, 0f, 0f),
    new Vector3(3f, 0f, 0f),
    new Vector3(4f, 0f, 0f)
};
}

void Start()    {

lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer> ();
lr.positionCount = 0;
DrawBezierCurve ();

}
public Vector3 GetPoint (float t) {
return transform.TransformPoint(Bezier.GetPoint(points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3], t));
}

public void DrawBezierCurve ()  {
lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer> ();
lr.positionCount = 1;
lr.SetPosition(0, points[0]);

for (int i = 1; i < numPoints+1; i++) {
    float t = i / (float)numPoints;
    lr.positionCount = i+1;
    lr.SetPosition(i, GetPoint(t));
}
}

public Vector3 GetVelocity (float t) {
return transform.TransformPoint(
    Bezier.GetFirstDerivative(points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3], t)) - transform.position;
}

public Vector3 GetDirection (float t) {
return GetVelocity(t).normalized;
}
}
```

BezierCurveEditor:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(BezierCurve))]
public class BezierCurveEditor : Editor {

private BezierCurve curve;
private Transform handleTransform;
private Quaternion handleRotation;

private const int lineSteps = 10;

private const float directionScale = 0.5f;

private void OnSceneGUI () {
curve = target as BezierCurve;
handleTransform = curve.transform;
handleRotation = Tools.pivotRotation == PivotRotation.Local ?
    handleTransform.rotation : Quaternion.identity;

Vector3 p0 = ShowPoint(0);
Vector3 p1 = ShowPoint(1);
Vector3 p2 = ShowPoint(2);
Vector3 p3 = ShowPoint(3);

Handles.color = Color.gray;
Handles.DrawLine(p0, p1);
Handles.DrawLine(p2, p3);
Handles.DrawBezier(p0, p3, p1, p2, Color.white, null, 2f);

curve.DrawBezierCurve ();

if (GUI.changed) {
    curve.DrawBezierCurve ();
    EditorUtility.SetDirty( curve );
    Repaint();
}

}


private void ShowDirections () {
Handles.color = Color.green;
Vector3 point = curve.GetPoint(0f);
Handles.DrawLine(point, point + curve.GetDirection(0f) * directionScale);
for (int i = 1; i <= lineSteps; i++) {
    point = curve.GetPoint(i / (float)lineSteps);
    Handles.DrawLine(point, point + curve.GetDirection(i / (float)lineSteps) * directionScale);
}
}

private Vector3 ShowPoint (int index) {
Vector3 point = handleTransform.TransformPoint(curve.points[index]);
EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
point = Handles.DoPositionHandle(point, handleRotation);
if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()) {
    Undo.RecordObject(curve, "Move Point");
    EditorUtility.SetDirty(curve);
    curve.points[index] = handleTransform.InverseTransformPoint(point);
}
return point;
}
}
```

BezierPair:

```
public class BezierPair : MonoBehaviour {


public GameObject bez1;
public GameObject bez2;

public void setupCurves()   {
    bez1 = GameObject.Find("Bez1");
    bez2 = GameObject.Find("Bez2");
}
}
```

BezierPairEditor:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(BezierPair))]
public class BezierPairEditor : Editor {

private BezierPair bezPair;

 public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    bezPair = target as BezierPair;

    if (bezPair.bez1.GetComponent<BezierCurve>().points[0] != bezPair.bez2.GetComponent<BezierCurve>().points[0])
    {
        Vector3 assignPoint0 = bezPair.bez1.GetComponent<BezierCurve>().points[0];
        bezPair.bez2.GetComponent<BezierCurve>().points[0] = assignPoint0;

    }
     if (GUI.changed)
    {

        EditorUtility.SetDirty(bezPair.bez1);
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(bezPair.bez2);
        Repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need it for 3d or 2d?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I need it in 2d

Comment: You should look at geometric continuinty.
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness)
[img1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#/media/File:Parametric_continuity_C0.svg)
[img2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#/media/File:Parametric_continuity_vector.svg)

Comment: @Bane, has any answer worked for you?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I just updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**

I dont think you'll need your `BezierPair` class. I suggest you to add a reference to the other `BezierCurve` object you want to "pair" as a public field on the `BezierCurve` class (`paired`). That other curve will get "paired" with this curve. Once paired, the constraints on the movement may apply. You can control the desired behaviors with the 3 public bool fields `behavior1`, `behavior2` and `behavior3`.

**Note#1**: Instead of calling the method `DrawBezierCurve` from the Editor, I added the `[ExecuteInEditMode]` to the Component Class. This way, You don't mix responsibilities between the Component and the Editor: The BezierCurve component draws itself on the scene, while the BezierCurveEditor only manages edit logic, like applying the constraints and drawing the handlers.

### BezierCurve:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
[ExecuteInEditMode] // Makes Update() being called often even in Edit Mode
public class BezierCurve : MonoBehaviour
{

  public Vector3[] points;
  public int numPoints = 50;
  // Curve that is paired with this curve
  public BezierCurve paired;
  public bool behavior1; // check on editor if you desired behavior 1 ON/OFF
  public bool behavior2; // check on editor if you desired behavior 2 ON/OFF
  public bool behavior3; // check on editor if you desired behavior 3 ON/OFF
  LineRenderer lr;

  void Reset()
  {
    points = new Vector3[]
    {
      new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f),
      new Vector3(2f, 0f, 0f),
      new Vector3(3f, 0f, 0f),
      new Vector3(4f, 0f, 0f)
    };
  }

  void Start()
  {
    lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
  }

  void Update()
  {
    // This component is the only responsible for drawing itself.
    DrawBezierCurve();
  }

  // This method is called whenever a field is changed on Editor
  void OnValidate()
  {
    // This avoids pairing with itself
    if (paired == this) paired = null;
  }

  void DrawBezierCurve()
  {
    lr.positionCount = numPoints;
    for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
      // This corrects the "strange" extra point you had with your script.
      float t = i / (float)(numPoints - 1);
      lr.SetPosition(i, GetPoint(t));
    }
  }

  public Vector3 GetPoint(float t)
  {
    return transform.TransformPoint(Bezier.GetPoint(points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3], t));
  }

  public Vector3 GetVelocity(float t)
  {
    return transform.TransformPoint(Bezier.GetFirstDerivative(points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3], t)) - transform.position;
  }

  public Vector3 GetDirection(float t)
  {
    return GetVelocity(t).normalized;
  }
}
```

**Note#2**: The desired behavior were coded inside the handler drawing methods, so you have access to Undo and other features.

**Note#3**: `EditorUtility.SetDirty` is [considered obsolete](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) since Unity 5.3 for marking objects as dirty for drawing, and *should no-longer be used for modifying objects in scenes*. `Undo.RecordObject` does the job.

### BezierCurveEditor:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

// This attribute allows you to select multiple curves and manipulate them all as a whole on Scene or Inspector
[CustomEditor(typeof(BezierCurve)), CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class BezierCurveEditor : Editor
{
  BezierCurve curve;
  Transform handleTransform;
  Quaternion handleRotation;
  const int lineSteps = 10;
  const float directionScale = 0.5f;

  BezierCurve prevPartner; // Useful later.

  void OnSceneGUI()
  {
    curve = target as BezierCurve;
    if (curve == null) return;
    handleTransform = curve.transform;
    handleRotation = Tools.pivotRotation == PivotRotation.Local ? handleTransform.rotation : Quaternion.identity;

    Vector3 p0 = ShowPoint(0);
    Vector3 p1 = ShowPoint(1);
    Vector3 p2 = ShowPoint(2);
    Vector3 p3 = ShowPoint(3);

    Handles.color = Color.gray;
    Handles.DrawLine(p0, p1);
    Handles.DrawLine(p2, p3);
    Handles.DrawBezier(p0, p3, p1, p2, Color.white, null, 2f);

    // Handles multiple selection
    var sel = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(BezierCurve), SelectionMode.Editable);
    if (sel.Length == 1)
    {
      // This snippet checks if you just attached or dettached another curve,
      // so it updates the attached member in the other curve too automatically
      if (prevPartner != curve.paired)
      {
        if (prevPartner != null) { prevPartner.paired = null; }
        prevPartner = curve.paired;
      }
    }
    if (curve.paired != null & curve.paired != curve)
    {
      // Pair the curves.
      var partner = curve.paired;
      partner.paired = curve;
      partner.behavior1 = curve.behavior1;
      partner.behavior2 = curve.behavior2;
      partner.behavior3 = curve.behavior3;
    }
  }

  // Constraints for a curve attached to back
  // The trick here is making the object being inspected the "master" and the attached object is adjusted to it.
  // This way, you avoid the conflict of one object trying to move the other.
  // [ExecuteInEditMode] on component class makes it posible to have real-time drawing while editing.
  // If you were calling DrawBezierCurve from here, you would only see updates on the other curve when you select it
  Vector3 ShowPoint(int index)
  {
    var thisPts = curve.points;
    Vector3 point = handleTransform.TransformPoint(thisPts[index]);
    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
    point = Handles.DoPositionHandle(point, handleRotation);
    if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
    {
      if (curve.paired != null && curve.paired != curve)
      {
        Undo.RecordObjects(new Object[] { curve, curve.paired }, "Move Point " + index.ToString());
        var pairPts = curve.paired.points;
        var pairTransform = curve.paired.transform;
        switch (index)
        {
          case 0:
            {
              if (curve.behavior1)
              {
                pairPts[0] = pairTransform.InverseTransformPoint(point);
              }
              break;
            }
          case 1:
            {
              if (curve.behavior2)
              {
                var p1 = handleTransform.TransformPoint(thisPts[1]);
                pairPts[1] += pairTransform.InverseTransformVector(point - p1);
              }
              break;
            }
          case 2:
            {
              if (curve.behavior3)
              {
                var p0 = handleTransform.TransformPoint(thisPts[0]);
                var p3 = handleTransform.TransformPoint(thisPts[3]);
                var reflect = Vector3.Reflect(p3 - point, (p3 - p0).normalized);
                pairPts[2] = pairTransform.InverseTransformPoint(p3 + reflect);
              }
              break;
            }
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        Undo.RecordObject(curve, "Move Point " + index.ToString());
      }
      thisPts[index] = handleTransform.InverseTransformPoint(point);
    }
    return point;
  }
}
```

For have it working, reference one `BezierCurve` to another's paired field through inspector, and set ON/OFF the behaviors you want.

**Tips**: tinker the properties of the `LineRenderer` to get cool gradients or width variation (like a brush stroke). If you have a cusp node and want it to look continuous, increase the value of `End Cap Vertices` on the Line Renderer. Use `Sprites-Default` as Material, for 2D.

Comment: you are creating two curves within another curve. Also the points are not all updating. I just updated the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "creating 2 curves"? They are not being created, they are being referenced. You can create as many curves as you want/need and you can link as many of those as you want with this approach. But, if you want it to work only and always with just 2 curves, pls let me know so I update the answer.

Comment: @Bane, I edited again, corrected some error with local x global coordinates. Now it have the desired behaviors.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to referencing two curves within another. It is  working, but I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this without referencing one curve within the other and without calling `[ExecuteInEditMode]`?

Comment: I think '[ExecuteInEditMode]' is desirable in this case. BezierCurve is a component with only one task: draw itself. Usually, you want this behavior to execute while editing, and not only when the game is running. But, if you prefer, you can get rid of it; but you will only see the effect on the other object when you select it. About the referencing stuff, I can think of something.

Comment: What about this; when you select 2 BezierCurve objects, the options to turn the behaviors on/off appear? (no other class nor reference needed).

Comment: I like the bezier curve selection option, I think that would really work well. The main reason I was thinking about a workaround `[ExecuteInEditMode]` is that I foresee myself working with a very large number of curves. Maybe, a way to only check for curve updates when they are selected or something could do.

Comment: I don't think this needs another question. In my opinion it will be better solving it here rather than asking another question that is heavily dependent on this one.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't heard from you since I awarded you the bounty. :)

Comment: That's because I got busy in my work (and it has been 1 day of inactivity, pls...), but I think this conversation is more suitable for the chat.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/164911/how-to-create-an-illustrator-photoshop-like-pentool-for-creating-bezier-curves-i

Answer (score 0):

> I tried solving 1. in the code below but the position for the second
>   curve wouldn’t update without my selecting BezierPair in the hierarchy
>   window

This is because you are using `OnInspectorGUI()` callback inside your `BezierPairEditor` class. It is only executed when the inspector of `BezierPairEditor` is shown on your editor window. Thus if you do not click on the `GameObject` with the `BezierPair` component, the `BezierPair`'s inspector is not shown, and the callback does not trigger.

Instead, use the `EditorApplication.update` delegate. Inside your `BezierPairEditor` class:

```
void OnEnable() {
    EditorApplication.update += OnUpdate; //Register to the update callback
}

void OnUpdate() {
    //Implement your code to update positions here
}
```

Secondly, try caching your `BezierCurve` references. This is because you don't really want to run `GetComponent` inside every update loop, as it is costly. Again, inside your `BezierPairEditor` class (I will omit the code above for clarity, merge it yourself):

```
BezierCurve bez1C;
BezierCurve bez2C;

void OnEnable() {
    BezierPair pair = target as BezierPair;
    bez1C = pair.bez1.GetComponent<BezierCurve>();
    bez2C = pair.bez2.GetComponenet<BezierCurve>();
}

void OnUpdate() {
    //Do something with bez1C and bez2C here
}
```

Finally, to solve points 1 to 3, since you did not specify, I shall assume that you are moving `bez1` manually, and `bez2` should follow. In the case where either one can be moved manually and the other should follow, I would recommend you to implement an `isChanged` check in your `BezierCurve` class. Then in your `BezierPairEditor` class, you can check which one has moved, and update the other one accordingly.

Inside `BezierPairEditor` class (again, I will omit the code above for clarity, merge it yourself):

```
Vector2 bez1CPrev1;

void OnEnable() {
    bez1CPrev1 = bez1C.points[1];

    //Ensure that they have the same starting point
    //Either you shift just points[0] of bez2 to be the same as bez1, or you shift every point. Implement this yourself.
}

void OnUpdate() {
    Vector2 disp = bez1C.points[1] - bez1CPrev1;

    //1. 
    bez2C.points[0] = bez1C.points[0];

    //2.
    bez2C.points[1] = bez2C.points[1] + disp;

    //3. Here, we are gonna use Vector2.Reflect(). Why? 
    //Imagine throwing a ball from newP2(curve1) to P3(curve1).
    //If the 'surface' that the ball hits has a normal of P0(curve1)-P3(curve1), you will have the ball bounce back to reach newP2(curve2).
    //Effectively: newP2(curve2) = P3(curve1) + [newP2(curve2) - P3(curve1)]. The term in the square brackets, we will do it with Vector2.Reflect().
    bez2C.points[2] = bez1C.points[3] + Vector2.Reflect(bez1C.points[3] - bez1C.points[2], (bez1C.points[0] - bez1C.points[3]).normalized);

    //Draw your bezier curve etc. here

    bez1CPrev1 = bez1C.points[1];
}
```